# SQL Need days of selected week as columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

Im in current need of making a query that returns based on a week all the days between the week but I need to use them as columns so that I can use rows per day for that week, I took an example I found here on forums

---

```
;WITH TestData(N, Order_Date, Net_Amount) AS (
    SELECT 1 N, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) Order_Date, RAND() * 100 Net_Amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 N, CAST(GETDATE()-N/5 AS DATE) Order_Date, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100 Net_Amount FROM TestData
    WHERE N < 20
    )
SELECT TestData.Order_Date, TestData.Net_Amount INTO #Order FROM TestData


SET DATEFIRST 1
;WITH Days(N,DayOfTheWeek)  AS (
    SELECT 1 N, DATEADD(DAY,  1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) DayOfTheWeek
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 N,DATEADD(DAY, 1, DayOfTheWeek) DayOfTheWeek FROM Days
    WHERE N < 7
)
SELECT d.DayOfTheWeek, SUM(Net_Amount) TotalAmount 
FROM Days d
LEFT JOIN #Order ON d.DayOfTheWeek = Order_Date
GROUP BY d.DayOfTheWeek
```

---

This is my end result

[image: 1]

But I need to display the days of the week in columns instead of rows

Result expected

[image: 3]

thx for your help

Comment: tag the dbms you are using

Comment: Why driver id doesn't appear anywhere in your query?

Comment: Preview pic was just an example not the actual data that I needed to show but I already replaced my  pic so its more clear what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: You have to use date as column group.